# add_rewrite_rule confusion

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have this function in my functions.php of a localhost build:-

```
function custom_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('.*', 'http://example.com/', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite');
```

As far as I understand, this should redirect *any* page to example.com. But it's not working. The page loads as normal with no redirect. I've tried flushing after adding the rule, but no joy.

Obviously, I don't actually want to redirect all pages like this, but I'm trying to get a basic rewrite working before fine-tuning it to my needs. But I can't even get over this first hurdle!

I've followed countless tutorials online and can't get any of them to work. Is there a prerequisite for using add_rewrite_rule? And if not, anybody have any idea why this won't work? Is it because I'm in a localhost environment?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT

I followed Jack's advice and changed my rewrite rule to:-

```
add_rewrite_rule('.*', 'index.php?page_id=81', 'top');
```

But I'm still not having any luck. I also tried changing the .* catch all to an actual existing pagename like so:-

```
add_rewrite_rule('^testpage/?', 'index.php?page_id=81', 'top');
```

And still no redirect.

The page with ID 81 exists as does 'testpage'. Im stumped. Should rewrite rules work on a localhost build? Any further illumination anybody can offer?

Comment: Rewrite rules should point to `index.php`. Have you checked the official [codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) for this function? It's pretty straight forward.

Comment: I didn't realise it was explicit. That would explain a lot! Thanks for the education Jack. So, is it impossible using the rewrite API to redirect to a page thats not part of the wordpress install? For example, if I had a "test.php" file in the wordpress root.

Comment: The Rewriting API is for rewriting URLs, not redirecting. So the URL won't change. You're just telling WordPress that `/testpage/` should load `page_id` `81`, but the URL will stay `/testpage/`. But I tried `add_rewrite_rule('^testpage/?', 'index.php?page_id=501', 'top');` (where 501 is an ID that exists on my install) and it worked fine, loading that page's content and template. Make sure you're [flushing rewrite rules](https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/) though. It won't work unless you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

The Rewriting API is for rewriting URLs, not redirecting. So the URL won't change. You're just telling WordPress that `/testpage/` should load `page_id` `81`, but the URL will *stay* `/testpage/`.

Regardless, I tried the below, (where 501 is an ID that exists on my install) and it worked fine, loading that page's content and template:

```
function wpse_283104_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^testpage/?', 'index.php?page_id=501', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_283104_rewrite' );
```

*Make sure you're [flushing rewrite rules](https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/) though*. It won't work unless you do.

If you just want to do redirects, then [.htaccess or a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/) is probably the way to go.

If you *really* want to use a rewrite rule for a redirect, then what you need to do is rewrite the URL to set a custom query var, then check that query var in the `template_redirect` hook, and perform a redirect.

First up, we'll create a custom query var called `wpse_283104_redirect. A query var is a query string that WordPress recognises. We need to tell WordPress to see`?wpse_283104_redirect=1`in a rewrite so that we can check it later. This is done by filtering the`query_vars` array:

```
function wpse_283104_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'wpse_283104_redirect';

    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse_283104_query_vars' );
```

Next is the rewrite rule:

```
function wpse_283104_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^testpage/?', 'index.php?wpse_283104_redirect=1', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_283104_rewrite' );
```

Now `/testpage/` will load the homepage, but since we registered `wpse_283104_redirect` we can see if we're on `/testpage/` (or whatever the rewritten URL is) with [`get_query_var()][2]`.

So inside the `template_redirect` hook we'll perform this check and redirect:

```
function wpse_283104_redirect() {
    if ( get_query_var( 'wpse_283104_redirect' ) == '1' ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://example.com' );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_283104_redirect' );
```

Comment: If you’re just redirecting away, there’s no reason to wait until template_redirect. After query parsing but before the query is run will save you a trip to the database.

Comment: Fair call, what hook would you suggest, `init`?

Comment: Thanks Jacob. That all makes sense. I would rather use the htaccess file but I need to change these rewrites dynamically, so im not sure regular writing to the htaccess is a good idea. Hence my experiments with rewrite API. Your idea to use a query to trigger a redirect sounds feasible. Im going to give it a go...

Comment: @JacobPeattie `init` is too early, I think `parse_query` is the earliest action you could hook.